# ValueError: `labels.shape` must equal `logits.shape` except for the last dimension. Received: labels.shape=(786432,) and logits.shape=(262144, 23)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I try to train a DeepLabv3+ with drone-images. My dataset consits of images/masks with a dimension of 6000x4000. Images are in jpg-format and masks in png.
If I run the following Code, I get the ValueError: `labels.shape` must equal `logits.shape` except for the last dimension. Received: labels.shape=(786432,) and logits.shape=(262144, 23)

I am pretty new to Deep-Learning and glad for any advise.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from scipy.io import loadmat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

#Erstellung des Data-Sets
#
#
#
#
#
#
IMAGE_SIZE = 512
BATCH_SIZE = 1
NUM_CLASSES = 23
DATA_DIR = 'C:/Users/Julian/Desktop/semantic_drone_dataset_semantics/deeplab'
NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES = 380
NUM_VAL_IMAGES = 20


train_images = sorted(glob(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "images/*")))[:NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES]
train_masks = sorted(glob(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "masks/*")))[:NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES]
val_images = sorted(glob(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "images/*")))[NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES : NUM_VAL_IMAGES + NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES]
val_masks = sorted(glob(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "masks/*")))[NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES : NUM_VAL_IMAGES + NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES]






def read_image(image_path, mask=False):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    if mask:
        image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=3)
        image.set_shape([None, None, 3])
        image = tf.image.resize(images=image, size=[IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE])
    else:
        image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=3)
        image.set_shape([None, None, 3])
        image = tf.image.resize(images=image, size=[IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE])
        image = image / 127.5 - 1
    return image


def load_data(image_list, mask_list):
    image = read_image(image_list)
    mask = read_image(mask_list, mask=True)
    return image, mask


def data_generator(image_list, mask_list):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_list, mask_list))
    dataset = dataset.map(load_data, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
    return dataset


train_dataset = data_generator(train_images, train_masks)
val_dataset = data_generator(val_images, val_masks)

print("Train Dataset:", train_dataset)
print("Val Dataset:", val_dataset)

#DeeplabV3+ erstellen
#
#
#
#
#
#
def convolution_block(
    block_input,
    num_filters=256,
    kernel_size=3,
    dilation_rate=1,
    padding="same",
    use_bias=False,
):
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        num_filters,
        kernel_size=kernel_size,
        dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
        padding="same",
        use_bias=use_bias,
        kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.HeNormal(),
    )(block_input)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)


def DilatedSpatialPyramidPooling(dspp_input):
    dims = dspp_input.shape
    x = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(dims[-3], dims[-2]))(dspp_input)
    x = convolution_block(x, kernel_size=1, use_bias=True)
    out_pool = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(dims[-3] // x.shape[1], dims[-2] // x.shape[2]), interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)

    out_1 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=1, dilation_rate=1)
    out_6 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=6)
    out_12 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=12)
    out_18 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=18)

    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([out_pool, out_1, out_6, out_12, out_18])
    output = convolution_block(x, kernel_size=1)
    return output

def DeeplabV3Plus(image_size, num_classes):
    model_input = keras.Input(shape=(image_size, image_size, 3))
    resnet50 = keras.applications.ResNet50(
        weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=model_input
    )
    x = resnet50.get_layer("conv4_block6_2_relu").output
    x = DilatedSpatialPyramidPooling(x)

    input_a = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(image_size // 4 // x.shape[1], image_size // 4 // x.shape[2]),
        interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)
    input_b = resnet50.get_layer("conv2_block3_2_relu").output
    input_b = convolution_block(input_b, num_filters=48, kernel_size=1)

    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([input_a, input_b])
    x = convolution_block(x)
    x = convolution_block(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(image_size // x.shape[1], image_size // x.shape[2]),
        interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)
    model_output = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same")(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=model_output)


model = DeeplabV3Plus(image_size=IMAGE_SIZE, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
model.summary()

#Modell trainieren
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
loss = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    loss=loss,
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=25)

plt.plot(history.history["loss"])
plt.title("Training Loss")
plt.ylabel("loss")
plt.xlabel("epoch")
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history["accuracy"])
plt.title("Training Accuracy")
plt.ylabel("accuracy")
plt.xlabel("epoch")
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history["val_loss"])
plt.title("Validation Loss")
plt.ylabel("val_loss")
plt.xlabel("epoch")
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history["val_accuracy"])
plt.title("Validation Accuracy")
plt.ylabel("val_accuracy")
plt.xlabel("epoch")
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are using the wrong activation function and not using the correct output layer for classification. You should be using a Dense layer with `softmax` activation function as the output layer.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I am a bit confused. Where do I have to change it ?

Comment: Depends on how your model should be designed. But since you're using the accuracy metric with sparse categorical cross entropy, your last layer should be a Dense layer with the number of classes as the number of neurons, with theb softmax activation function. You're currently using a Conv2D layer.

Comment: Thank you again for helping me. I got this model directly from the keras site and I am honest, I am at the very beginning of understanding what is happening here. 
Can I add this new layer by putting "layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,
...                               activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)" in the convolution_block, or can I simply replace the model_output by :"layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,
...                               activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)" ?

Comment: I would probably just replace the last layer with the dense layer instead of adding a new one. That final convolutional layer is already defined incorrectly.

Comment: You dont know how glad I am. Can you show me how to do this ? Can I just replace"model_output = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same")(x)" with "model_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)" ?

Comment: Are you trying to do image classification or are you trying to recreate images? If you're doing classification, then geez you'd change it to that. If you're trying to recreate images, it'd be completely different along with your `model.compile()` call.

Comment: okay for further understanding, I try to do a semantic segmentation on this drone-data-set:https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/bulentsiyah/semantic-drone-dataset. And for a model I need to use Deeplabv3+. So I got the model directly from the keras-site, and now i am applying my Input to the given model.

Comment: Disregard what I was saying, I thought you were doing image classification, not classification within the image.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which does *not* work by simply throwing all our code here as-is; please post the *full* error trace, and remove any code that comes *after* the error (since it is never executed, hence it is irrelevant to the issue). See how to create a [mre] and why [a wall of code isn't helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/).

Answer (score 0):

The mask needs to be 1-dimensional:

```
if mask:
        image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=1)
        image.set_shape([None, None, 1])
```

You have `3` and that's why you have 3 times as many labels

Comment: Thank you very much, at least its training now, but i keep in mind what @Djinn ist saying

Comment: my problem now, is that i am using colored masks with 23 different classes. So i have to load 3 channels or am I wrong ? 
Because thats what I am getting :
Epoch 1/25
380/380 [==============================] - 32s 73ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0011 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0017
Epoch 2/25
380/380 [==============================] - 27s 71ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0011 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0017``

Comment: The last layer is correct. You can't use a dense layer there, it wouldn't make sense. You want a 1x1 convolution, and each `pixel` is supposed to be treated equally. That's why conv and not dense. Additional, a dense layer would give you about '(512*512)*(512*512)' parameters, that's not possible to do

Comment: Yes, but their metric, activation function, and loss function wouldn't be accuracy, softmax, and sparse catergorical cross entropy. That with a final Conv2D layer doesn't make sense, hence the further questions. What yo're describing is not classification, which is what the code in OP's question is suggesting.

Comment: It is correct. It's not an image. Each pixel is given a category

Comment: Input is an image. Output has same shape as the image, except the last dimension, which gives the logits for that particular pixel

Comment: I guess thats what you mean right ? :
Epoch 1/25
380/380 [==============================] - 33s 74ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0011 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0017
Epoch 2/25
380/380 [==============================] - 27s 71ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0011 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0017
Epoch 3/25
380/380 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0011 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0017
Epoch 4/25
380/380 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0011 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0017

Comment: @jules2703 Your model output is a map 512x512x23. For each pixel you need to take argmax over the last dimension, and you will have the chosen category for that pixel. It's up to you how you create a color map out of that

Comment: But the loss values shouldn't be nan though, right?

Comment: no, `nan` is not good

Comment: I guess its not that easy to train a given model with different image.data; the example on the keras-site with that model works with greyscale-mask-data. Could that be the problem ?

Comment: @jules2703 your masks should not be colored images. They need to be in the format `size x size x 1`. Each pixel value should be between 0-22 and be the category that pixel belongs to. If you have an colored image with 23 colors as a mask, you need to transform it accordingly